# Adding or inviting someone to my Trello board

Tags: trello, invitation

What steps or procedure do I follow in order to invite someone to my Trello board?

Answer (score 4):

1. In web browser click on board you want to invite someone to.
2. On the top right side click on Add members. Another input will appear where you put in email address of the person.
3. The person will receive an email invitation and will have to sign up.
4. After that you can change permission of members by clicking on their image (top right side).